# How is a repository supposed to get internal state of an aggregate without ORM in DDD context?

Tags: domain-driven-design, repository

Domain objects (aggregates and entities) are only exposing behavior and no dummy `getter()` or `setter()` methods. If I don't want to use an ORM in a repository which is capable of extracting internal state by means of reflection, then how a repository is supposed to get internal state of an aggregate?

Comment: There is no answer there, but it is still a duplicate.

Comment: Expose a DTO and give your domain objects internal conversion to and from it.

Comment: @Ewan I added a comment to the following question. You mean something like this? http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/266425/best-practices-for-serialization-of-ddd-aggregates#comment720725_266437